# Reducing number of hours from a given Time through PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I am trying to reduce number of hours from given time, but when I do it with AM/PM it doesn't give proper result, below is my code what I am trying to do

```
<?php
    $gmt_time = gmdate("h:iA");
    $times = date('h:iA', strtotime("-5.00 hours", strtotime($gmt_time)));
    echo $times;
?>
```

At the time of my code execution $gmt_time was 03:19AM

Expected Output :
$times should be : 10:19PM

Actual Output : 
$times is 10:19AM

Comment: for what its worth, if you happen to want to test out [`DateTime`](https://3v4l.org/jZNE0) classes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the DateTime classes.

```
<?php
$timeOffset = "-5 hours";
$time = date_create("Now UTC")
  ->modify($timeOffset)
  ->format("h:iA")
;
echo $time;
```